# Get the stack of the "parent" goroutine along with that of the "child"

Tags: go

Is there a way in go, possibly with some debug flag switched on, to obtain a dump of the stack traces of all goroutines along with the stack traces of the "parent" goroutines (using "parent" here to mean the goroutine that executed the call to `go foo()` that launched the goroutine in question). The context for this question is that I have a connection leak and noticed there are many goroutines blocked on `awaitDone` (in the sql package), and these goroutines were spawned where the connections were created.

Comment: The normal output (e.g. on a panic) does this already as much as it is logically *possible*: Note that not every running goroutine has a live parent. The parent goroutine might have terminated long ago. So what is the question?

Comment: I mean the stack as of the time the goroutine was created. It would presumably require a debug flag so that goroutines can have this information stored along with them when they are created so this debug context is available when the stack trace is requested.

Comment: That time has passed and the information is no longer there.

Answer (score 2):

`runtime.Stack()` will give you all the stack information that the runtime is aware of.

Reading the output you can see, for Goroutines, they are designed to contain no information of its ancestors.

However, in the stack output, you do have access to where a goroutine was created. You can, technically, auto cross match that with other Goroutine's stack output to deduce the topology **partially** and **inaccurately**.

AFAIK, this is how many Golang IDEs tackle the debugging problem. Unless Golang core team changes its mind on Goroutine's metadata, I think this is the best option possible.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand what you're asking, you can probably print/output the info you want using the runtime package.

Take a look at 
https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller and the skip paramter. Plus the frame docs: https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Frames

Is that what you're after?